# How can I align my header svg with my nav bar?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have been looking through stack and other resources, but I can't find anything that perfectly fits what I have been trying really hard to do. I made my header as an svg with a rectangle going across, and I want my nav bar buttons to continue along with the rectangle. Currently, I have the display set as block, but then I can't seem to shift the button upward to align perfectly with the header's rectangle. Instead, the text of the buttons is lower aligned with the svg, instead of the bottom border of the button's padding. Please help me format this!

My code with the svg is here: http://jsfiddle.net/stvyrn0x/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>emily waxler</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <header>
            <img src="signature.svg" alt="emily">
            <nav>
                <button>main</button>
                <button>portfolio</button>
                <button>resume</button>
            </nav>
        </header>
    </body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
header img {
    width: 67vw;
    display: inline;
}

nav {
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 4vh;
    width: 33vw;
}

nav button {
    color:#000000;
    background-color: #FFCB74;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0vw;
    max-width: 7vw;
    font-size: 1vw;
    height: 6.22vw;
    padding: 3vw 2vw;
    border-style: none;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dqeknatr/ - would recommend learning about flexbox and grid to help with layout.

Comment: @sol OP wants to align with the rectangle in the svg not to the top.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and portable way is to create the svg without the bottom padding under the rectangle.
[image]

As, you can see, it is the culprit of why the rectangle doesn't align. You can probably use `position: relative` to forcefully shift the element. But it would very likely not be portable on device with different viewport, unless your svg will be of fixed size.

Answer (score 0):

Add `position:relative;bottom: 3vw;` inside `nav button{}` of style.css